Not able to add glyph to a font using python
I am trying to create a new font using some glyph of my own using python. I have have a function to parse the SVG file representing a glyph and converts it into a FontTools TTGlyph object.The function returns the generated TTGlyph object (glyph), the glyph name (glyph_name), and the extracted codepoints (codepoints). Now i am trying to create a font using these values. I got a script for this:
def create_font_from_glyphs(glyph_data, output_path):
    font = TTFont()

    font['head'] = newTable('head')
    font['head'].unitsPerEm = 1000

    font['hhea'] = newTable('hhea')
    font['hhea'].ascent = 900
    font['hhea'].descent = -100

    font['maxp'] = newTable('maxp')
    font['maxp'].numGlyphs = len(glyph_data) + 1  
    font['glyf'] = newTable('glyf')

    for glyph, glyph_name, _ in glyph_data:
        font['glyf'][glyph_name] = glyph

    cmap = newTable('cmap')
    cmap.tableVersion = 0
    cmap.tables = []
    subtable = CmapSubtable.newSubtable(4)
    subtable.platformID = 3
    subtable.platEncID = 1
    subtable.language = 0
    subtable.cmap = {unicode: glyph_name for _, glyph_name, unicodes in glyph_data for unicode in unicodes}
    cmap.tables.append(subtable)
    font['cmap'] = cmap

    font_name = "Example Font"
    name = newTable('name')
    name.names = []  
    nameRecord = NameRecord()
    nameRecord.nameID = 1
    nameRecord.platformID = 3
    nameRecord.platEncID = 1
    nameRecord.langID = 0x409
    nameRecord.string = font_name.encode('utf-16-be')
    name.names.append(nameRecord)
    font['name'] = name

    font['post'] = newTable('post')
    font['post'].italicAngle = 0
    font['post'].underlinePosition = -100
    font['post'].underlineThickness = 50
    font['post'].isFixedPitch = 0
    font.save(output_path)
def main():
    svg_dir_path = "data/svg" 

    glyph_data = []
    for filename in os.listdir(svg_dir_path):
        if filename.endswith('.svg'):
            svg_file_path = os.path.join(svg_dir_path, filename)
            glyph, glyph_name, codepoints = parse_svg_to_glyph(svg_file_path)
            glyph_data.append((glyph, glyph_name, codepoints))

    create_font_from_glyphs(glyph_data, "test.ttf")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I am getting this error:
font['glyf'][glyph_name] = glyph
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^
 self.glyphs[glyphName] = glyph
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
 AttributeError: 'table__g_l_y_f' object has no attribute 'glyphs'

I am expecting to add the glyphs to the font.
